# Matlab session-based interface: rapidly update analog output

Tags: matlab

I would like to control a piezo driven z-stage (for microscopy) through a simple analog output (0-10V) by using a NI DAQ board and the Matlab session-based interface. This works so far but I need to dynamically update the z-postion very rapidly (best under 20 ms). However queuing and executing an updated voltage value takes over 150 ms right now. Is there any way to optimize this? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
%% initialize DAQ, specify output channels and refreshrate
devices = daq.getDevices
s = daq.createSession('ni');
s.addAnalogOutputChannel('Dev1', 'ao0', 'Voltage');
s.Rate = 1000; %1ms refreshrate

%define output data (I only define one data point as DAQ board keeps that voltage until changed)
zVol = 4.8; % range of stage is 100 um => 10um/V

%Queue output data
s.queueOutputData(zVol);

%output signal
s.startBackground();
```

Comment: I found a solution by using the legacy interface in the data acquisition toolbox. One can use the putsamle function:

`%% create an analog output, add 2 analog output channels and directly output a voltage`

`ao = analogoutput('nidaq','Dev1');`

`addchannel(ao,0);`

`voltage=4;`

`putsample(ao,[voltage voltage])`

The putsample function executes in 2 ms on my system